# Windows Update: Can not clean install fresh windows 2012 Essentials server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-update

Am attempting to install Windows 2012 Essentials on a Dell CS24-TY 1U Server, two disks, Raid1.

Note: Completely clean installation, for a small company, no existing domain controller, no other servers at all, original installation media, couldn't possibly be a more simple setup.

Am unable to get Windows 2012 server to install at all, if I allow it to try an update while installing - it just hangs on 0% at "Updating and preparing your Server".  I have tried installing via Dell Drac remotely mounted media, local USB key, and local usb-attached DVD drive.

If I set the server to install without processing updates, it will install, but if I then try to run Windows Update it just again hangs forever.  I have tried stopping the wuauserv service, and removing the Software Distrubtion folder etc, nothing appears to work.

I have also tried removing the RAID and installing just to a single disk: same result.

Nearly all references I find to "Windows Update not working" are based on an established machine that has somehow got corrupted etc - not on a brand new vanilla installation of Windows Server.

Does anyone have some pointers how I could go about solving this problem?

Note: This is a 100% clean and simple base setup - zero configuration or roles or services etc. Nothing has been done to the OS other than what is required during installation: setting server name and password etc.

Thankyou.

### EDIT

Below are the last entries from WindowsUpdate.log, when it appears to hang.  Given that it was possible to install this exact OS Media on this exact Hardware before, is it possible that Microsoft have recently released an Update that breaks Windows Update?  Is it possible to translate the Update Guid to a KB number?

```
2017-01-18  15:11:14:840     412    1424    Agent   WARNING: Failed to evaluate Installable rule, updateId = {E66A6795-3E20-43ED-9C66-FE134EEEECBC}.200, hr = 80070057
2017-01-18  15:11:19:324     412    1424    Agent   Bundled update {FBEC0F80-9F87-4B42-BA14-2BBE7148322A}.203 is missing extended metadata
2017-01-18  15:11:19:324     412    1424    Agent   Bundle contains children which has no localextended metadata and thus is invalid.
2017-01-18  15:11:19:324     412    1424    Agent   Update {B27CF4B3-0B7D-475D-9129-883E6DED6182}.203 is not a valid bundle. Not returning it.
```

ipconfig /all

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : server1
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : FABLAB.local
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : FABLAB.local

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C8-0A-A9-C8-3B-8A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C8-0A-A9-C8-3B-8B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{468CFBC4-85E3-4EDA-96BC-6A3E4B842EA3}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{48398617-4417-4945-8A81-DE0F3BCC7D2B}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

nslookup google.com

```
Server:  localhost
Address:  127.0.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4006:80e::200e
          184.150.153.177
          184.150.153.158
          184.150.153.187
          184.150.153.183
          184.150.153.148
          184.150.153.153
          184.150.153.182
          184.150.153.163
          184.150.153.157
          184.150.153.167
          184.150.153.172
          184.150.153.152
          184.150.153.173
          184.150.153.178
          184.150.153.162
          184.150.153.168
```

Comment: One thing to try...do the install without updates...then make sure in IE under Lan Settings (connections) all are unchecked unless you absolutely do use a proxy.  Then try the updates.  That usually works.  There's also this Powershell option: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/11/08/use-a-powershell-module-to-run-windows-update/

Comment: Have you verified the IP configuration of the server? Does it have a valid IP address/subnet mask, default gateway and DNS server configured.

Comment: Thanks. No proxy server. Super simple network. Server accesses internet no problem. DNS is set to 127.0.0.1, havn't (yet) configured any DNS Server settings - as DNS works out of the box.

Comment: The server is configured to use itself for DNS. Do you have the DNS role installed on the server? Does the server have a valid ip address/subnet mask and default gateway?

Comment: Yes server can access internet, has valid ip etc. Tried with both DHCP and static assignments.  Have not installed DNS role (setup is **100% vanilla**), but DNS works and points to localhost, thus I can only assume that windows 2012 server installs DNS Server by default. I had also tried setting to 8.8.8.8, same issue.

Comment: Hmm... This doesn't quite make sense. The DNS server roles isn't installed by default. If the server is using 127.0.0.1 for DNS and the DNS server role is not installed then the server should not have DNS name resolution, and thus no internet connectivity (by DNS names). Dod you install AD AD and promote the server to a Domain Controller by any chance? Can you post a screenshot of Server Manager, ipconfig/all, and an nslookup query for google.com in your question?

Comment: Thanks Joe. Correct: I did not install DNS Server, yet (by default) it points to 127.0.0.1, and yes name resolution works, so clearly DNS Server role must be installed. To reiterate: I have done absolutly *zero* config, such as installing AD or promoting to a DC or activating DNS Server Role etc. Also reiterate: I am installing from original install media (no NTLite etc), and it is Server 2012 Essentials. (Perhaps it defaults to an AD controller by default?) Am offsite now, will post the information you have requested. P.S I am looking at slipstreaming all updates into the install using ntlite

Comment: Oh boy. My bad. I didn't pay attention to the fact that this is Windows Server Essentials. Yes, that will have installed AD DS and DNS as part of the install process, which explains why DNS resolution works. My apologies.

Comment: Nope, my bad actually. I initially omitted, by mistake, "Essentials" from the question. I had only added it later during an edit.  Apologies respectfully declined due to lack of any fault on your behalf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue:
- I attempted to update during installation and hung at 0%.
- I installed without updates, and after getting to desktop, attempted to run updates, which searches for updates indefinitely (18+ hours).
- I installed without updates, and tried to update using WSUS Offline Update, which hangs on "Listing IDs of Missing Updates" (13+ hours).
- I have attempted to install with the computer on an entirely different network/ISP to attempt to rule out DHCP/DNS server issues, with no change in behavior.

---

I managed to get Server 2012 Essentials installed and up to date using the following method:

1. Installed WSUS Offline Update version 10.9 (on a Win 10 x64 machine)*.
2. Downloaded updates for Server 2012 through WSUS Offline Update.
3. Installed NTLite (on a Win 10 x64 machine)*.
4. Followed this guide to package updates using NTLite - https://web.archive.org/web/20180129120711/http://www.v-strange.de/index.php/vmware/2-uncategorised/220-slipstream-windows-updates-to-server-2012r2-install-medium
5. Copied updated install.wim back onto the Server 2012 Essentials USB installation media
6. Installed Server 2012 Essentials on target machine, with the selection to install updates during installation checked.
7. After finalizing installation and rebooting, I was able to successfully pull down the remaining Windows Updates successfully.

*I mention the OS I worked from because Mtl Dev shared that he was unsuccessful following the guide linked in step 4 on a windows 7 machine.

(Partial credit goes to Mtl Dev for pointing me towards the WSUS Offline Update/NTLite solution to update the installation media prior to installing the OS.)